# iOS Safari applies landscape CSS first before applying portrait - how stop this?

Tags: ios, css, media-queries, mobile-safari

I have two media queries:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (orientation: landscape)" href="/stylesheet/landscape.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (orientation: portrait)" href="/stylesheet/portrait.css" />
```

In the first, one of the classes has a property that is not in the second:

```
/* This is how it is in landscape */
.myClass { position: relative; border-right: 1em solid red; }


/* This is how it is in portrait */
.myClass { position: relative;  }
```

Even loading the page in portrait view, it shows a border on the right! I can put the border property in portrait view to override this but is there any way to make Safari *not* apply the landscape css at all when it's in portrait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...just add in portrait view:

myClass { position: relative; border-right:0  }

edit: explanation: this happens because both files are loaded and all properties are applied in the same class. The position is overridden by the same name class in the second file but nothing overrides the border-right property.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to keep it from being applied first.

Comment: then also switch which file is loaded first. put portrait at top. IT would be for the best though if you merged both files into one and apply the media queries to the corresponding classes. They are both getting loaded anyway

Comment: "apply the media queries to the corresponding classes" that's much more of a mess to manage. It's cleaner to put them in separate files but just keep the order of classes the same.

Comment: what I meant was, merge both files and use two media queries, one to wrap each files contents. Also, less hits to the server. 'Cleaner' is subjective, I'd prefer one file from more than one.